# Handling Nested JSON Object via Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

Greetings and many thanks to the Stack Overflow community for all of the other awesome posts about the Facebook c# SDK. I have ran into a little challenge here and unfortunately I have not been able to find a previously posted solution.

**How are you guys handling** processing an **nested JSON Object** within a **JSON response from the Facebook Open Graph API?** For example, I am having some trouble getting to the nested **venue JSON object** that is returned when you retrieve a specific **Facebook Event** via the Open Graph: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Here is some of the code that I am working with to provide more specific context:

```
var fbApp = new FacebookApp();
var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer(fbApp);

    if(auth.IsAuthorized())
    {
        //output the FB user's Event
        dynamic result = fbApp.Api("/" + EventID);

        txtEventDesc.Text = result.name;
        txtEventLoc.Text = result.location;
        txtEventInfo.Text = result.description;

        foreach (dynamic vi in VenueInfo.data)
        {
            //txtStreet.Text =  vi.street;
        }

     }

    ...
```

So, how would you handle this embeded venue JSON object? Thanks in advance for taking the time to read my question and offer direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dynamic result = fbApp.Api("/" + EventID);    
dynamic street = result.venue.street;
```